# position:fixed doesn't work inside cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport

Tags: css, angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

HTML element with **position:fixed** doesn't work inside **cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport**.
Below style should put the element at the page top left corner, but this class doesn't apply to elements inside cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport.

.fixed-div {position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;}

for some reason above class to elements inside cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport will keep the elements at the top left corner of cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport.

link to reproduce https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvf6dp

How to force elements with position:fixed inside cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport to display the relative to viewport ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the css transform property on the `div.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper` element. The transform property makes and child that is position fixed treat that parent as the containing block rather than the body of the page.

See here for details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Still trying to figure out how to deal with this myself.

Comment: Hey guy, do you have any progress?